# Finding files without a specific extension

Tags: regex, unix

can anyone help me with a regex that will find files that dont have a .tar.gz extension

i need it to work in my unix script

```
for i in <REGEX for non tar.gx files>
do
something
done
```

thanks

Comment: Note that `for i in blah` doesn't use regular expressions, it uses shell pathname expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Never, never, never use regexes for the task "match every X that doesn't match Y". Instead, use the trivial regex for X and negate the result.

(In shell expressions, replace `==` with `!=` , or use `grep -v` . In Perl, use `!~` instead of `=~` . In JQuery, use the `:not` operator, etc. If your API doesn't allow you to do anything else but specify one single regex, beat the vendor over the head with Chomsky's *A hierarchy of formal languages*.)

Complemented regexes are always either inefficient, unreadable or engine-specific - usually all of the above. Just say no to abuse of regexes, use tools for the tasks they're good at!

Answer (score 3):

In bash, with extglob turned on (which appears to be the default) you can negate a glob by using `!(<glob>)`.  So:

```
for i in !(*.tar.gz)
do
    something
done
```

If you wanted to match two globs, you'd write `for i in *.tar.gz *~`.  Similarly, you can write `for i in !(*.tar.gz|*~)` if you want to match all files that are neither gzipped archives nor backup files.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use extended globbing, you can also include a simple test:

```
for file in *
do
    if [[ $file != *.tar.gz ]]
    then
        something
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (which illustrates an often-overlooked technique) is simply:

```
ls | grep -v 'pdf$'|while read i; do echo "i=$i"; done
```

This is hammer-to-crack-a-nut territory for this particular problem, but if you need to do something with a set of files with slightly complicated selection criteria, this can pay off quite quickly.

And it'd work in any sh-like shell.

Comment: But it fails on filenames with control characters since `ls` tries to sanitize them.

Comment: True, but if you have filenames with control characters in them, you probably have other problems (and not necessarily specifically technical ones)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find` as well...

```
find . -type f -not -iname "*.tar.gz"
```